# Spring Boot Test - field injection raises NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit4

I'm writing test for rest app in spring boot.

But in my test, interface CategoryService in CategoryController cannot be autowired when running test and NullPointerException raised.

**CategoryService is injected at field level.**

Here my classes:

**CategoryController**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/categories")
public class CategoryController {

    @Autowired
    private CategoryService categoryService;

    @RequestMapping
    public List<Category> getAll() {
        return categoryService.findAll();
    }
}
```

**CategoryService**

```
@Service
public class CategoryServiceImpl implements CategoryService {

    @Autowired
    CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Category> findAll() {
        return categoryRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

**CategoryRepositoryImpl**

```
@Repository
public class CategoryRepositoryImpl  implements CategoryRepository {
    @Override
    public List<Category> findAll() {
        ... 
    }

}
```

**----- TEST ------**

**AppTestConfig**

```
@Configuration
public class AppTestConfig {

    @Bean
    public CategoryRepository categoryRepository() {
        return new TestCategoryRepository();
    }

    @Bean
    public CategoryService categoryService() {
        return new App.CategoryServiceImpl(); 
    }
}
```

**CategoryControllerTest**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes =  {AppTestConfig.class})
public class CategoryControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    @Test
    public void testGetAll() throws Exception {
        CategoryController controller = new CategoryController();
        List<Category> categories = controller.getAll();
        assertEquals(categoryRepository.findAll().size(), categories.size());
    }
}
```

With constructor injection, everything works fine.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know without seeing the whole project, but please try adding some more annotations :-) :

1. `@ComponentScan` on AppTestConfig - to ensure that all beans are available
2. `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` instead of `@ContextConfiguration` - I think this is always the case for Spring Boot
3. `@WebAppConfiguration` on CategoryControllerTest - Web App context may be needed for servlets if you are using Spring MVC.

Comment: Thank you for answer,  @burna 's suggestion helped me.

Answer (score 3):

You are constructing the `CategoryController` by using the `new` keyword. In this way, spring doesn't know this object, therefore it can't inject anything into it.

The bean should by instantiated by spring, just like the `CategorService`, the object under test can be setup in the spring `Configuration` class.

If spring creates the bean, it will autowire the relevant properties.

```
@Autowired
private CategoryController underTest;
```